# IS there a do not match function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to do 2 functions. The first is to match all the values (text) from 1 range with another and return the values that match. I would also like a second formula that returns the values that do not match. The 2 lists may not be in the same order nor can they be as they are ranked.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($L$4:$L$23,MATCH($B15,$L$4:$L$23,0)),$L15&" Different")
```

Could anyone suggest an answer?

Thank you in advance

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/398521/excel-get-cell-value-which-is-not-match-in-a-row) seems to be similar, you might want to investigate that further?

Comment: Not the same. I want it to return the values that are different. From what I can see this does not do that it puts NO instead. Thanks for your reply though. If I have misunderstood your link please explain.

Comment: It's not exactly the same I'll grant you that but I think they're after the same type of thing and there may be a way to use some of the techniques in a similar fashion. They're looking for the matches where it doesn't equal "NO", and you're looking for values where it doesn't equal your match.

Comment: You are right and I did try to use this with a colleague at work but we could not get it to do the same function. Any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: I think the issue for me is that the 2 lists might be different order so it does not know which value to return that does not match.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native function of the kind I think you require.

With two unsorted ranges, say B4:B25 and L4:L25, one can identify matches and non-matches with Conditional Formatting and then perhaps might choose to filter by colour to extract matches or non-matches.

Select both ranges and (standard) fill red. Select B4:B25 and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=COUNTIF(L$4:L$25,B4)
```

Format..., select green (suggestion) fill, OK, OK.

Then select L4:L25 and repeat CF with:

```
=COUNTIF(B$4:B$25,L4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that IFNA(INDEX($L$4:$L$23,MATCH($B15,$L$4:$L$23,0)), "NO MATCH") would help you solve this.